# Creating an empty object with nested attributes in Python

Tags: python, object, attributes, nested

I'm trying to create an empty object which contains nested attributes like this:

```
form = type('', (), {})()
form.foo.data = ''
```

But I get following attribute error:

```
>>> form = type('', (), {})()
>>> form.foo.data = ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data'
```

How should I construct the object to accomplish that?

Comment: how do you want to use this?

Comment: Well the class constructor would be the `Form` class from `WTForms`. But in this case I only want to create a 'fake' object which only contains those attributes: `form.foo.data` or `form.bar.data` and so on.

Comment: @Navidad20 It's for a test case. I need to assign the values to those attributes manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the type function , the third argument should be in the form of dictionary. So, for nested attributes, you can create the object before itself and then use it in the dictionary.
Something like this might work -

```
da = type('',(),{'data':1})    
a = type('',(),{'foo':da})
```

Comment: This way looks good, but I think we have a "better" way to do this with MagicMock, [like in this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691261/7195250)

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your point but you may use `namedtuple` :

```
>>>from collections import namedtuple

>>>foo = namedtuple('foo', "data tuple dict")
>>>foo.data = ""
''
>>> foo.tuple = ()
>>> foo.tuple
()
```